# Is it possible to check a file name exist no matter the file's extension in PHP on Windows XP?

Tags: php, file

E.g:

the Folder name:

```
myFolder
```

files inside myFolder:

```
myFolder.01.mkv
myFolder.01.avi
myFolder.02.avi
```

...

And I just want to check that the file name exist or not.Just like.[ ignore the extension]

```
file_exist('d:\\myFolder\\myFolder.01');
```

Thank you very much!!

[update]

I want to check the file exist before I re-name the file.But it seems that glob() function will not work when the file doesn't exist.

E.g:

```
$path = glob("d:\\myFolder\\myFolder.99.*"); // myFolder.99.* doesn't exist and glob didn't work
```

Comment: As already said in your last question, `glob()` will help. Something like `if count(glob("myFolder.01.*") > 0) .....`

Comment: edit your previous question, it's obvious they are the same.

Comment: You are right! Using count()! Thank you very much!! I'll do more study on glob()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's glob function to prevent specifying the extension. However this may result in a security issue:

https://www.php.net/glob

```
glob($file . ".*")
```

Comment: There are indeed different glob() implementation issues on different operation systems, so I'd rather prefer using scandir() + its results comparison to name pattern solution instead.